# Android check existence of file in android internal storage

Tags: android, file, internal-storage

I put some .mp4 file in a folder in my android device internal storage. And then I play this file from my application. It plays well if exists otherwise app crushed.
So before play file I want to check its existence.
I tried below code but no luck.

```
File file = new File("file:///storage/emulated/0/tutorial/1a1cbfc4-18cb-4637-8405-01bf9bebeda3.mp4");
    if (file.exists()) {
        LogUtil.printLogMessage(VideoListActivity.class.getName(), "video File", "file exist");
    } else {
        LogUtil.printLogMessage(VideoListActivity.class.getName(), "video File", "file not exist");
    }
```

i am sure the file is exist in the folder named tutorial in my internal storage.

Comment: Just use a easy name for your file

Answer (score 0):

Use `file.isFile()` for file  & `file.isDirectory()` for directory,
`file.exists()` tries to access the file which causes it to crash if the file doesn't exist, `file.isFile()` uses linux [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), which only returns the information about the file without trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Please make proper file name, Replace with `File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);`

```
public Boolean checkFile(){
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/tutorial/1a1cbfc4-18cb-4637-8405-01bf9bebeda3.mp4");
    if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use checkfile True/False flag before video play.

Comment: You should remove "file://" in the URL or the test will not work. I made the edit in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
  File file = new File(path);
  if (!file.isFile()) {

  }else{

  }
```